# Java: How can I improve my code for performance?

Tags: java

I have a program that reads a .txt file from a given directory. Each record line contains a data and I am parsing it. I think this is costly with it comes to performance but I might be wrong. Here is the method. How can I improve it to improve performance?

```
    currentLine = uploadFileReader.readLine();

    while (!isBlankOrNull(currentLine)) {                 
                line++;
                String[] record = parseRecord(currentLine);
         // process the record array here..
    }

    private String[] parseRecord(String currentLine){

        String[] recordLine = currentLine.split("\\|");
        String[] record = null;
        String[] zeroArray = null;          

        if(recordLine.length == 4){
            zeroArray = new String[] {"0","0","0","0","0","0"};
            record = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(recordLine, zeroArray);
        }else if(recordLine.length == 5){
            zeroArray = new String[] {"0","0","0","0","0"};
            record = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(recordLine, zeroArray);  
        }else if(recordLine.length == 6){
            zeroArray = new String[] {"0","0","0","0"};
            record = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(recordLine, zeroArray);  
        }else if(recordLine.length == 7){
            zeroArray = new String[] {"0","0","0"};
            record = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(recordLine, zeroArray);  
        }else if(recordLine.length == 8){
            zeroArray = new String[] {"0","0"};
            record = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(recordLine, zeroArray);  
        }else if(recordLine.length == 9){
            zeroArray = new String[] {"0"};
            record = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(recordLine, zeroArray);  
        }else{
            record = recordLine;
        }

        return record;
    }
```

Sample File content:

```
    0000710000|07-23-2015|08-24-2015|257072140993|1|0.2|0.3|||
```

Each null/blank pipes will have "0" default values

Comment: "I think this is costly with it comes to performance"... Is it fast enough?  If so STOP! Have you tested it on maximum realistic inputs?

Comment: Well, the file have a 2000 lines of records and it took me around 6 minutes to end the processing.. It is kinda slow right?

Comment: Moreover, that's not a question for SO. Instead, it's for codereview.

Comment: Oh. thanks. I'm unaware that there is a codereview

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: Can you post part of the example file... say the first 5 lines just to see the context? Also how many files? Is the file on the local filesystem... or mounted share etc?

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/110427/9357).

Answer (score 1):

The only explanations I can think of for that taking 6 minutes to read a 2000 line file are:

- You are using an unbuffered reader.
- The individual lines are very long.
- Both of the above.

In either case, a good way to identify performance bottlenecks is to use a profiler.

---

If (hypothetically) the problems are caused by one of the above, you can improve read times by (respectively):

1. wrapping the `Reader` with a `BufferedReader`,
2. using a `Scanner` to read directly from the reader rather than reading a whole line and splitting, and
3. avoid holding the entire file content in memory.

I'm inclined to the opinion that 2. won't make a lot of difference, and 3. won't either unless the file is VERY big.

Comment: Here is my Reader. uploadFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(uploadFile));

Comment: In that case, the performance is inexplicable.  PROFILE IT.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite this more simply as follows. The requirement appears to be return an array of String always length 10 with "0" filling any unused cells?

Without real test data I cannot comment on its relative performance to your original, it does however significantly "less" work, less array allocations, condition checking etc, so is "very likely" to be faster...

```
private String[] parseRecord(String currentLine) {
    String[] recordLine = currentLine.split("\\|");
    String[] record = new String[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < record.length; i++) {
        if (i < recordLine.length) {
            record[i] = recordLine[i];
        } else {
            record[i] = "0";
        }
    }
    return record;
}
```

Test

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseRecord("1")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseRecord("1|2")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseRecord("1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseRecord("1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10")));
}
```

Output

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```